# Why is the InfoPath Data Connection Wizard failing?

Tags: infopath

I am running SharePoint Enterprise on a local VM. I am able to connect to the server using SharePoint Designer 2010 without issue.

However, when I use InfoPath, the Data Connection Wizard fails.

If the entered URL is anything but http://domain/sites, the connection fails with "The operation could not be completed".

If URL ends at /sites/, I am queried for my Farm credentials, so I know that the connection is being made, but the credentials are rejected.

I have burned a few hours on this issue. Can anyone help?

- I have InfoPath Form Services enabled
- I have a form library
- I have create a list to connect to